# replace login option from navbar to profile

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

How can I dynamically replace the login option in the navbar with a profile option dropdown (containing options like "Edit Profile" and "Logout") upon user login? Despite successful logout implementation, upon page refresh, the profile menu persists instead of switching back to the login menu. How can I maintain the visibility of the login menu after a page refresh, ensuring that the login menu appears instead when the user logs out and refreshes the page?
**login code**

```
<?php
 session_start();

// Include your database configuration or connection file
include('includes/config.php');


// Login Handling
if (isset($_POST['login'])) {
    $email = $_POST['loginEmail'];
    $password = $_POST['loginPassword'];

    $sql = "SELECT Emailid, Password, FullName FROM tbluser WHERE Emailid=? and Password=?";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bind_param('ss', $email, $password); // 'ss' indicates two string parameters
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->get_result();

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
        $_SESSION['login'] = $row['EmailId'];
        $_SESSION['fname'] = $row['FullName'];
        header("Location: index.php"); 
// Redirect to index page after successful login
        exit;
    } else {
        echo "<script>alert('Invalid Details');</script>";
    }
    $stmt->close();
}
?>
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

**This is Script for the code which is not working**

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        // Function to create the profile dropdown menu
        function createProfileDropdown() {
            return $('<div class="nav-item dropdown">' +
                    '<a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Profile</a>' +
                    '<div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">' +
                    '<a class="dropdown-item" href="profile.php">View Profile</a>' +
                    '<a class="dropdown-item" href="edit_profile.php">Edit Profile</a>' +
                    '<a class="dropdown-item" id="logoutLink" href="#">Logout</a>' +
                    '</div>' +
                    '</div>');
        }

        // Function to create the login link
        function createLoginLink() {
            return $('<a href="login.php" class="nav-item nav-link">Login</a>');
        }

        // Append the profile dropdown menu to the appropriate location in your navigation bar
        var profileDropdown = createProfileDropdown();
        $('.navbar-nav').append(profileDropdown);

        // Click event handler for logout link
        $('#logoutLink').on('click', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            // Perform logout functionality (e.g., redirect to logout.php)
            // After successful logout, replace the profile dropdown with the login link
            var loginLink = createLoginLink();
            $('.nav-item.dropdown').replaceWith(loginLink);
        });
    });
</script>
```

**Navbar Code**

```
<!-- Topbar Start -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
<div class="container-fluid bg-dark py-3 px-lg-5 d-none d-lg-block">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 text-center text-lg-left mb-2 mb-lg-0">
          <div class="d-inline-flex align-items-center">
            <a class="text-body pr-3" href=""
              ><i class="fa fa-phone-alt mr-2"></i>+91 6359783824</a
            >
            <span class="text-body">|</span>
            <a class="text-body px-3" href=""
              ><i class="fa fa-envelope mr-2"></i>info@wheeslonweb.com</a
            >
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 text-center text-lg-right">
          <div class="d-inline-flex align-items-center">
            <a class="text-body px-3" href="">
              <i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i>
            </a>
            <a class="text-body px-3" href="">
              <i class="fab fa-twitter"></i>
            </a>
            <a class="text-body px-3" href="">
              <i class="fab fa-linkedin-in"></i>
            </a>
            <a class="text-body px-3" href="">
              <i class="fab fa-instagram"></i>
            </a>
            <a class="text-body pl-3" href="">
              <i class="fab fa-youtube"></i>
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Topbar End -->

    <!-- Navbar Start -->
    <div class="container-fluid position-relative nav-bar p-0">
      <div class="position-relative px-lg-5" style="z-index: 9">
        <nav
          class="navbar navbar-expand-lg bg-secondary navbar-dark py-3 py-lg-0 pl-3 pl-lg-5"
        >
          <a href="" class="navbar-brand">
            <h1 class="text-uppercase text-primary mb-1">Wheels On Web</h1>
          </a>
          <button
            type="button"
            class="navbar-toggler"
            data-toggle="collapse"
            data-target="#navbarCollapse"
          >
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>
          <div
            class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-between px-3"
            id="navbarCollapse"
          >
            <div class="navbar-nav ml-auto py-0">
              <a href="index.php" class="nav-item nav-link  ">Home</a>
              <a href="about.php" class="nav-item nav-link">About</a>
              <a href="service.php" class="nav-item nav-link">Service</a>
              <div class="nav-item dropdown">
                <a
                  href="#"
                  class="nav-link dropdown-toggle"
                  data-toggle="dropdown"
                  >Cars</a
                >
                <div class="dropdown-menu rounded-0 m-0">
                  <a href="car.php" class="dropdown-item">Car Listing</a>
                  <a href="detail.php" class="dropdown-item">Car Detail</a>
                  <a href="booking.php" class="dropdown-item">Car Booking</a>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="nav-item dropdown">
                <a
                  href="#"
                  class="nav-link dropdown-toggle"
                  data-toggle="dropdown"
                  >Pages</a
                >
                <div class="dropdown-menu rounded-0 m-0">
                  <a href="team.php" class="dropdown-item">The Team</a>
                  <a href="testimonial.php" class="dropdown-item"
                    >Testimonial</a
                  >
                </div>
              </div>
              <a href="contact.php" class="nav-item nav-link">Contact</a>
              
              


    
    <!-- Other navbar links -->
  
<!-- JavaScript for Logout Handling -->
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        // Function to create the profile dropdown menu
        function createProfileDropdown() {
            return $('<div class="nav-item dropdown">' +
                    '<a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Profile</a>' +
                    '<div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">' +
                    '<a class="dropdown-item" href="profile.php">View Profile</a>' +
                    '<a class="dropdown-item" href="edit_profile.php">Edit Profile</a>' +
                    '<a class="dropdown-item" id="logoutLink" href="#">Logout</a>' +
                    '</div>' +
                    '</div>');
        }

        // Function to create the login link
        function createLoginLink() {
            return $('<a href="login.php" class="nav-item nav-link" id="loginLink">Login</a>');
        }

        // Check if user is logged in (You may need to adjust this //condition)
        var login = <?php echo isset($_SESSION['login']) && $_SESSION['login'] === true ? 'true' : 'false'; ?>;

        // Append the appropriate navigation element based on user's //`enter code here`login status
        if (login) {
            var profileDropdown = createProfileDropdown();
            $('.navbar-nav').append(profileDropdown);
        } else {
            var loginLink = createLoginLink();
            $('.navbar-nav').append(loginLink);
        }

        // Click event handler for logout link
        $(document).on('click', '#logoutLink', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            // Perform logout functionality (e.g., redirect to //logout.php)
            // After successful logout, replace the profile dropdown with the login link
            var loginLink = createLoginLink();
            $('.nav-item.dropdown').replaceWith(loginLink);
        });
    });
</script>
            </div>
          </div>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- nav bar end -->
```

//please reply as soon as possible this is my final year project

Comment: `please reply as soon as possible`... please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326569/under-what-circumstances-may-i-add-urgent-or-other-similar-phrases-to-my-quest). This is an encyclopaedia of useful programming questions, not a helpdesk or troubleshooting service. Please also take the [tour] and read [ask], as you were prompted to do before posting anything (but I can see from your profile you did not). You can [edit] your question whenever you like. Thanks

Comment: Anyway it seems to work up to a point as far as I can see - demo: https://jsfiddle.net/6aqn8Lku/ . If you click "logout" then the link is replaced with "login" - which you said wasn't happening. However it's also replacing all the other dropdowns with "login" as well, because you targeted the dropdown class used by all the dropdown menus, not just the specific menu you're interested in. You need to target the exact menu  - easiest way would be to give it an `id`, and select it with that. This has nothing to do with PHP, btw. And are you using bootstrap? If so please state the version.

Comment: by repacing i mean change to login when user click on logout from profile dropdown but when i refresh page the login option disappears and it acts as already logged in

Comment: If you're talking about when the page refreshes, well you would need to check the PHP $_SESSION['login'] value when you're building the page, and then decide whether to show the login or logout button based on that.

Comment: it worked when i added the same login logic in header page thanks